# Firebase onComplete never called in background process

Tags: android, firebase, broadcastreceiver, firebase-realtime-database

**My goal**

To build an app that allows users to turn location tracking on & off. When tracking is on, I want to push the user's location data to Firebase.

**My attempted solution**

I use PendingIntent and the Google Play Services FusedLocationAPI to track location in the background. At every location update (punctuated by 30s), the PendingIntent fires off an intent (with a location update, if available) to a WakefulBroadcastReceiver. The WakefulBroadcastReceiver should then save the location data to Firebase.

Here is what the WakefulBroadcastReceiver looks like:

```
public class LocationProcessingReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationProcessingRcv";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (LocationResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            Log.i(this.TAG, "Received location result");

            // Extract location from result and push to server
            Location location = LocationResult.extractResult(intent).getLastLocation();
            this.pushLocationToServer(location, intent.getStringExtra("userId"));
        }
        else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No location result");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Pushes location to Firebase server
     * @param location
     */
    private void pushLocationToServer(Location location, String userId) {

        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // Data to update the latest status of the user
        Map<String, Object> statusMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // ... various statusMap.put(...) calls go here

        // Get reference to Firebase as well as key at which to update reference
        DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        dbRef.child(DB_LOC_HISTORY_REFERENCE).push().updateChildren(historyMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError == null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Successfully pushed to server");
                }
                else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Server push failed: " + databaseError.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**The problem**

On some phones, the onComplete callback is never called (on some devices!). I have no idea why this isn't working... On some devices the callback works as expected. On others, the callback is never received and I never see the data updated in Firebase.

The Logs show that the location updates are working just fine, and that the WakefulBroadcastReceiver's onReceive() method is called periodically, as expected.

I would have expected onComplete to be called, but to show an error if there is a connection issue. But that never happens, and I am struggling to understand why.

**A Caveat:** Many of these devices are running on 3G. Is it possible that, when my app is in the background, the BroadcastReceiver is killed before Firebase can finish doing it's thing, perhaps because the 3G connection is too slow?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be related to the lifecycle of a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

The documentation explains that:

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call
>   to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this
>   function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer
>   active.
>
> This has important repercussions to what you can do in an
>   onReceive(Context, Intent) implementation: **anything that requires
>   asynchronous operation is not available**, because you will need to
>   return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at
>   that point the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active and thus **the
>   system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation
>   completes**.

Because the FirebaseDatabase operations are performed asynchronously on a background thread, the system will, in some cases, destroy your `LocationProcessingReceiver` instance before the DB operation is performed.

You may think that using a [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) will prevent the receiver object from being destroyed prematurely, but that is not the case. `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` is intended to be used to securely start a service, which you are not doing here.  It is of no benefit.  Use a  `BroadcastReceiver` instead.

To ensure the DB operation is allowed to complete, aquire a [Wakelock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) in `pushLocationToServer()` (maybe with a timeout for safety) and then release it in the `onComplete()` callback.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there a way to keep the BroadcastReceiver alive until Firebase finishes it's job? Or generally *any* way to ensure that the FirebaseDatabase operations aren't interrupted?

Comment: I edited my original post to add a suggestion to use a Wakelock.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot. It seems a little hacky though... is it better to have a Service with a Firebase connection always running in the background, and for my BroadcastReceiver to simply call "pushToServer" on this reference? Not sure how I would implement this, but what do  you make of it conceptually?

Comment: Update: this did not work either. I think the issue is entirely different: I think I am losing my connection to Firebase, and Firebase never reestablishes the connection in the background once it's lost.

Comment: The connection is automatically closed when not needed, but should be reactivated by the call to `updateChildren()`.  Try enabling debug logging: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)`.